# Wordpress Permalink Hidden Link

Tags: wordpress, hidden, permalinks

Wordpress' permalink structure means that even if you don't put in the exact URL it redirects you to the most similar URL if there's something similar.

E.g.

Permalink = http://test.com/this-is-a-test-site-asdr5646/
Navigating to http://test.com/this-is-a-test-site/ would take you there.

This usually is suitable but I want to created hidden posts that are only accessible by using the exact URL, is this possible without creating a complex non-pretty URL?

Comment: You can always protect your hidden post with password if you do not want visitors to open it...

Comment: True but then that requires handing out passwords to everyone. I'd rather have a URL that has to be exact to be access but when passed round works for anyone. Similar to the "Unlisted" feature in YouTube.

Comment: Alright, did you tried this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hide-post/